# Masonry plug-in not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, jquery-masonry

I recently took an interest in building websites and am still very inexperienced, so my apologies if this is easily answered.

I was asked by a friend to build her a simple portfolio website for fashion designs. As such, the website mainly has image galleries. The images come in various sizes and rather than ordering them manually to make it look better, I found the Masonry plugin. I implemented masonry.pkgd.min.js into my code (initialized through the HTML) and ran into two issues:

1. The main issue that might make question 2 moot entirely… It looks fine in IE and Firefox, but the images come up overlapping in Chrome and it looks horrible. I cleared my cache several times and tried implementing the imagesLoaded plug-in, which did absolutely nothing. I am very new to Javascript and as such have to rely on copy/pasting this sort of plug-in whereas someone else might be able to delve in and tweak it, but at the same time I had no issues getting tabbed content and this does work in two browsers. Any idea why it doesn’t work in Chrome and what I can do to fix it?
2. After the plug-in, I don’t seem to have any control over automatically centering the image columns in the gallery/container and they are aligned left by nature. I more or less fixed this by manually setting a margin-left that puts everything in the right place, but would like to know if there is a better solution.

Please let me know if I need to include screenshots or specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue One:**

Try adding [imagesLoaded](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#imagesloaded). Chrome in particular has an issue if you don't use it with masonry.  I suggest trying the solution in the third box first, it's the easiest and fastest loading.  This code will go in your .js file if you have one, or in your script tags if you don't.

If the "why" interests you, it's because your containers load before your pictures and don't know how tall they should be.

**Issue Two:**

You're right on with this one.  You can't center the whole masonry container itself (you can get close, but at certain browser widths there will be a small gutter on the right), but you can center the images within their containers by adding a margin like you did or using:

```
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Chrome not loading the images properly was really annoying me.